# Rounding number without using Math.ceil() javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I want to round a number to nearest value but without using a Math.ceil() function in javascript.

usually we do

```
Math.ceil(23.99) = 24
```

But how can we achieve it without using Math.ceil()
for e.g.

```
100.99 -> 101
34.78 -> 35
2.999 -> 3
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve it with plain javascript. Unfortunately, i could not find a solution online.

Comment: What's the question/problem? There are hundreds of similar questions on SO -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: And this has absolutely nothing to do with `arrays`, `reactjs`, `json` or `object`

Comment: This has also nothing to do with `html` or `formatting`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **toFixed()** method and pass the number of digits that you need after decimal. See below examples

```js
console.log("100.99 -> " + (100.99).toFixed(0));
console.log("34.78 -> " + (34.78).toFixed(0));
console.log("2.999 -> " + (2.999).toFixed(0));
```